# Axosoft RocketSVN VS. VisualSVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, visualsvn

I've been a long time user of [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) (pretty much since the beginning), but I often have problems with little things like renaming files in a solution and then not committing properly (or whatever) and causing the commit to break.

Now I've just seen that [Axosoft](http://www.axosoft.com) is giving [RocketSVN](http://www.axosoft.com/rocketsvn) away FREE, and I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this?

Is it worth the switch?  Is it good subversion software?  Does it have any deal breaking bugs?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Since everyone is saying that RocketSVN is built on [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), can I ask.  What are the differences between AnkhSVN and VisualSVN?  Is one better than the other?

Comment: Has anyone else even used RocketSVN?

Comment: The differences between AnkhSVN and VisualSVN are +- the same as the accepted answer when you substitute AnkhSVN for RocketSVN. For more see: http://bit.ly/dM3wBo

Comment: From what I have seen the Agent SVN Subversion plugin handles renaming of files from inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to follow up, I've been using RocketSVN for a couple of months now, and I really like it.  Here's what I see

VisualSVN

- traffic light icons
- integrates with Visual Studio
- works great with my SVN software (VisualSVN Server)

RocketSVN

- traffic light icons
- integrates with Visual Studio
- works great with my SVN software (VisualSVN Server)
- **does NOT require TortoiseSVN**
- can add commit comments without committing the source (not sure if this was available in VS SVN)

RocketSVN wins IMO

#### Jan 28, 2011

Adding to this answer: I was just at the Axosoft website, and it appears that RocketSVN and RocketSVN Server are now FREE for unlimited users. So price is no longer a deterrent.

Comment: FYI, axosoft reason for making these free is that they have dropped both support & development for these products

Comment: sweet, random down vote on a 2 year old answer with no explanation... This community is really beginning to suck balls.

Comment: Why "does NOT require TortoiseSVN" is a pros?

Comment: It's just nice for there to be a stand alone program without the need for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)?  RocketSVN is a version of AnkhSVN with a few changes applied on top, so it's likely AnkhSVN will fit your needs.

Comment: The difference with RocketSVN is the integration with OnTime.  Since RocketSVN is currently free, I don't see a need to introduce another SVN solution into the mix.

Comment: The point is still, they use an existing extension mechanism in AnkhSVN to add OnTime support to RocketSVN. They could (and I think should) have just released the OnTime extension.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just an AnkhSVN client it should work fairly good. With AnkhSVN we have 2 issues, first it sometimes will crash in visual studio 2005 when committing. sometime .design.cs files are renamed with a capital D, when this happens a commit fails. Both issues are rarely seen and I can not reproduce them at te moment.

When one of these issues occurs the commits just fails so the repository stays consistent. From my point of view it is a stable and very usable client.

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  I have installed it and it appears to be really quite nice.  Still waiting to see what the OnTime integration looks like.